# No route matches {:action=>"show" in RSpec, fine in browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec

I have a `users_controller.rb` that includes:

```
before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
load_and_authorize_resource

def index
  @users = User.all
end

def show
end

def new
  @user = User.new
end

private
def set_user
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

My `config/routes` includes:

```
devise_for :users

devise_scope :user do
  authenticated :user do
    root 'switchboard#show', as: :authenticated_root
  end

  unauthenticated do
    root 'devise/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
  end
end

resources :users
```

When I navigate to `http://localhost:3000/users` I get a list of the users as I expect. But when I run the RSpec test:

```
require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe UsersController, :type => :controller do

  describe "GET show" do
    it "returns http success" do
      get :show
      expect(response).to be_success
    end
  end
end
```

I get the error `No route matches {:action=>"show", :controller=>"users"}` on the RSpec line `get :show`.

I've found countless queries about `No route matches {:action=>"show"`, each one with a different cause, but none of them seems to match mine. What do I do to fix this (other than not test the feature!)

Comment: But `/users` isn't the same as `/show`?

Answer (score 13):

Because you have no route that matches controller `user` action `show`

However, you do have a route that matches `user/:id` (it's the `:id` you're missing)

So you could do...

```
get :show, id: 1
```

Comment: wow, thanks! I can't believe how easy this is to miss. I'm surprised rspec doesn't do something to tell you it's missing an id instead of leaving it to the router.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me to :). Where can I find more explanations about this topic? Cause I didn't know how to write to rspec to access the routes of id... ?